# How can I open jupyter notebook from Anaconda Prompt? I'm having issues with it

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, anaconda3

I'm trying to open jupyter notebook, but it shows me this issue:
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\AREA 51.conda\envs\python_course\python.exe "C:\Users\AREA 51.conda\envs\python_course\Scripts\jupyter-script.py" notebook'
[image: the issue:]

I activated a new environment named "python_course" and then I installed jupyter notebook using this command: "conda install jupyter notebook", after  that I tried opening it using "jupyter notebook".
I tried running the prompt as administrator, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.